# How to create single file application?

Tags: application-development

I only know how to create .desktop application that is associated with .sh file. I want to create an executable application that doesn't call any file.

A simple example would be: an application that run a command line code.

Comment: shell scripts can (with set executable permission and correct shebang) be directly executed.

Comment: You should look for C++ Programming. I think what you want to know is how to write desktop applications.

Comment: As answer to your latest edit: That would definitely be as simple as a `.desktop` file. In the `Exec=` line, you can set any command you like, if you respect the syntax for the varying commands.

Comment: @JacobVlijm I will try it

Comment: @JacobVlijm I know what the OP is trying to tell. Examples : [qtox](https://build.tox.chat/view/Clients/job/qTox_build_linux_x86-64_release/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/qTox_build_linux_x86-64_release.tar.xz) or [clipgrab](http://download.clipgrab.de/clipgrab-3.5.6.tar.bz2).... these are single executable files. Double click on it, it will launch.

Comment: @SeverusTux Ah, of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple example to open Nautilus:

```
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Terminal=true
Exec=bash -c 'nautilus;'
Name=openNautilus
```

Comment: `#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open` is really outdated an unnecessary, while `Terminal=true` is actually incorrect, and `Exec=bash -c 'nautilus;'` ?? Furthermore, create multiple `.desktop`files running the same application in their "native" command is a bad idea...

Comment: @JacobVlijm I created an application to open nautilus, it works. Could you print your suggestion?

Comment: Sure, but you'd need another command :) As mentioned, creating a *second* `.desktop` file of nautilus is a bad idea. This https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/ar01s05.html is a nice source to get more information on keywords.